# How to generate dynamic navigation menus from the database using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a dynamic nested navigation menu depending on user login permissions retrieved from the database, I retrieve user permissions to drop-down menu options each option has userName;module;subModule;programe;programeLink;programeCode Separated by ";".
need to generate module text as the main menu, subModule text as subMenu1, the program as subMenu2, and program link in the "a href" for the program.
here what i tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" />');

function subModules1() {
    var subModules1Length = $('#userRights option').length;
    for (var i = 1 ; i <= subModules1Length; i++) {                             

$(".sub-menu-1").append("<ul><li class=\"hover-me\"><a href=\"#\">"+$("#userRights option:nth-child("+i+")").text()+"</a><i class=\"fa fa-angle-right\"></i></i></ul>") 

    }
  }

  $('#userName').change(function(){
    subModules1()
  });

  $(".forms").append("<div class=\"sub-menu-1\"></div>"); 

});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu-bar {
    background: rgb(0, 100, 0);
    text-align: center;
}
.menu-bar ul {
    display: inline-flex;
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
}
.menu-bar ul li {
    width: 120px;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
}
.menu-bar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.menu-bar ul li:hover {
    background-color: #2bab0d;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.menu-bar .fa {
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.sub-menu-1 {
    display: none;
}
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(0, 100, 0);
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
}
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ffffff;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
.menu-bar ul li:hover .sub-menu-1 ul li a:hover {
    color: #b2ff00;
}
.fa-angle-right {
    float: right;
}
.sub-menu-2 {
    display: none;
}
.hover-me:hover .sub-menu-2 {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -45px;
    margin-left: 140px;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-bar">
   <ul>
       <li class="forms"><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
       <li class="reports"><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<br>

<label for="User Name">User Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName"><br><br>
  
<label for="userRights">User Rights: </label>
<select id="userRights">
  <option value="userName;Forms;Time Attendance;Daily Attendance ;https://link1.com;001001001">userName;Forms;Time Attendance;Daily Attendance ;https://link1.com;001001001</option>
  <option value="userName;Forms;Time Attendance;Change Shift ;https://link2.com;001001002">userName;Forms;Time Attendance;Change Shift ;https://link2.com;001001002</option>
  <option value="userName;Reports;Project Control;Need Date;https://link3.com;002003006">userName;Reports;Project Control;Need Date;https://link3.com;002003006</option>
  <option value="userName;Reports;Project Control;Vacations;https://link4.com;002003005">userName;Reports;Project Control;Vacations;https://link4.com;002003005</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: need to split each line in drop menu user rights and generate it in navigation menu for example: forms: will be main menu,  Time Attendance will be text in sub menu1, Daily Attendance will be text in sub menu2, and link will be href for site.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize CSS plugin for multi-level menu

Please refer below sample for understanding

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_multi_level_css_menu_horizontal_blue/#